# Leave the <E> in ArrayList for the class to decide

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an interface for a databasetable handler in my application. And one of the methods looks like this:

```
void add(ArrayList<? extends BaseObject> object);
```

And depending on which class that implements I want the  to have different elemets.

For example, in one of my classes I want the following:

```
@Override
public void add(List<Category> object) {

}
```

And the class looks like this:

```
public class Category_Handler extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements HandlerInterface{

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}


@Override
public void add(ArrayList<Category> object) {
    //Preparing the database variables
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    for(int i = 0; i > objects.size(); i++){
        //Getting the values for the Category
        String name     = objects.get(i).getName();
        int subCategory = objects.get(i).getSubCat();

        if (db != null) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            //Adding values
            cv.put(Category_DAO.KEY_CATEGORY_NAME, name);
            cv.put(Category_DAO.KEY_SUBCATEGORY_TO, subCategory);

            //Finnish the insertion
            db.insert(Category_DAO.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

        }
    }
db.close();
}

@Override
public void remove(int id) {

}

@Override
public void edit(int id, ArrayList<Category> values) {

}
```

And Category looks like this

```
public class Category extends BaseObject{
private String name;
private int subCat;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getSubCat() {
    return subCat;
}

public void setSubCat(int subCat) {
    this.subCat = subCat;
}
```

}

The problem I'm facing now is when I change  to  I get an error message saying "Method does not override method from its superclass.

Anyone know if there is any way of solving this? Is there even possible to have a solution like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a generic interface that uses the type of the `add` method as its paramter like so:

```
public interface DatabaseHandler<T extends BaseObject> {
    public void add(ArrayList<T> objects);
}
```

Each of your classes could then implement the desired interface version:

```
public class CategoryHandler implements DatabaseHandler<Category> {
    @Override
    public void add(ArrayList<Category> objects) {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Then you need to bind the type, you cannot use the wildcard ?.

We need to see more code, but maybe something like

```
class DatabaseTableHandler<E extends BaseObject>{

   public void add(List<E> object){}

 }
```

and then you can do

```
class CategoryHandler extends DatabaseHandler<Category>{

      @Override
      public void add(List<Category> object) {}

}
```

But if this method does what it seems to be doing (adding all from the list), the signature should probably be

```
      public void addAll(List<? extends E> object){}
```

so that you can also accept a `List<SubCategory>`.  java.util.Collection#addAll also works like that.

Comment: so your `Handler` interface needs to have the bound generic type: `interface Handler<E extends BaseObject>`.

Comment: It doesn't fix it :S I added my code in the add method body to make it more clear of what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to restrict the type of `add` in subclasses, you can't use a wildcard. But I suspect that you actually don't need to use any kind of fancy generics at all for this case -- why not just have all subclasses implement `add(List<BaseObject> object)`? If `add` really just adds things to the list, then `List<BaseObject>` works just as well and comes with fewer headaches.

Comment: Thing is that he probably does not want any old BaseObject, but only the more specific Category.

Comment: `List<Category>` is no subtype of `List<BaseObject>` so that won't work

Comment: @Heuster true, but you can add `Category` instances to a `List<BaseObject>`. (You just can't rely on the items you pull out being `Category` objects.)

Comment: @Thilo I am assuming that given that the method is called "add" that the OP just wants to be able to add elements of type `Category`. If that's the case then you can add `Category` instances to a list of `BaseObject`s just fine.

Comment: @jacobm: It's the opposite though: Pulling things out of the list. (That is new information after OP added some code).

Comment: @Thilo Ah, I didn't see the edit. In that case, yeah, OP needs to use something like your solution.

Answer (score -1):

`BaseObject` is an abstract class so it has abstract methods that you have to implement. See The API of `BaseObject` to see the abstract methods that you have to implement. Your IDE should help you on this problem